# What is the best way to trigger a docker compose file from docker file?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am learning about docker recently so not clear on this part , suppose I am making a node js app where a frontend is been connected to mongo db , but I use a docker-compose file to spin up the mongo container every time I do development , now I have completely build my application and want to make a final docker file for it so that I can publish my image . What is the best way to do this ?

Idea -1

Should I wrap up my docker-compose file also in the final image so that from dockerfile before triggering the app using   `npm start` I should use trigger this docker-compose file

Or is there any other way in which i can directly spin up the container

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Docker/Compose expert either, but you usually reference your *Dockerfile* from *docker-compose.yml*, and not the other way around.

It'd be very helpful if you could share an example of your docker-compose.yml and expand on your deployment plan (local shell script? CI/CD on cloud? single host for all your services?).

Also, I encourage you to checkout the official [Use Compose in production](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/).

Comment: Thanks but i got my answer actually I was confused between docker compose and Dockerfile , my understanding is that in a deployment server we use up a docker compose to spin up all the containers, now here how Dockerfile comes in picture is that it is used to package your code into a image so that every-time you don't have to the same steps like npm install or anything.My question really was if my code is dependent on mongo image how production will know it so the answer is in production server you again will use docker compose file which will be used to spin up all the containers too